# change sklearn metrics module python

Tags: python, module, scikit-learn, edit, metric

After downloading sklearn package I've add the purity metric to sklearn metric module by adding it to **supervised**.py and **init**.py in cluster folder and **init**.py in metrics folder just the same as other metrics that are already in module. But after installing the package python recognize all other metrics except this one.

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'purity_score`

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER** change the code of any **library** you use !!

If you want to add a metric, `sklearn` allows you to do so using its [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) function.

`make_scorer` makes a scorer from a performance metric or loss function that you have customized.

Then you can use this scorer to perform your cross-validation. Take a look at the tutorial [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html).